# Correct way to iterate through a Json structure in Javascript for locate google maps marker

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I'd like to know why this function dont place any marker in my map.
im passing from my servlet to jsp an object marker that contains his title and the coordinate, this is a sample

```
<%=request.getAttribute("markers")%> = [{"lat":10.0,"lng":10.0,"title":"place"}];
```

and this is the javascript function

```
function placeMarker() {
    var json = <%=request.getAttribute("markers")%>;
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    for(var i in obj){
        var lat  = obj[i].lat;
        var lng  = obj[i].lng;
        var title = obj[i].title;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                title: title 
            });
    }
}
```

thank you for any suggestion and sorry for the bad english :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a string try something like this:

```
var json = '<%=request.getAttribute("markers")%>';
```